# How set path to root directory for pm2?

Tags: pm2

I have script server.mjs

```
-Root
-/node_modules/pm2/lib
-server.mjs
-package.json
```

I create ecosystem.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: "proxy",
    namespace: "localhost",
    script: 'server.mjs',
    watch: 'server.mjs',
    env_production: {
      NODE_ENV: "production"
    },
    env_development: {
      NODE_ENV: "development"
    }
  }],
};
```

In package.kson i have script

```
"server:start": "pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --only proxy",
```

Then i go ti page i see this

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/sergey/Desktop/newkind/node_modules/pm2/lib/index.html'
```

pm2 see root project dir is `/home/sergey/Desktop/newkind/node_modules/pm2/lib/`

Can i set path to root dir `/home/sergey/Desktop/newkind/` ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the one you're looking for..

There's the "cwd" option

link:
https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/